# How to structure a multi step wizard with ajax calls in angularjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I want to build a multi step wizard with ajax calls in between:

I currently use ui.router for views of the wizard steps which works fine.
On the first page the users enters some data e.g. `playerid`.
On the second page i want to display some data pulled from the server corresponding to that `playerid`.

How should i structure that? Because i read that controllers should only write to the model, but i need to read `playerid` the user entered to make the ajax call..?

Here is a Plunk how i do it right now:
http://plnkr.co/edit/4ZEdYHUqovn2YfkUpp2y?p=info

Comment: Could you provide a bit of your code ? (Like how you actually tried to do that)

Comment: @Okazari i added a Plunk

Comment: My idea was to do the ajax call in a function i add to the scope of the MainController. I would then call the function from an ng-click from the proceed button. But in that scenario i would read from the model in a controller which is a code smell AFAIK.

Comment: In my opinion if the model is passed in parameter in your function, that's not a controller "read" of the model.

Comment: @Okazari i updated the plunk, do you mean like that? Is this really best practice?

Comment: About the function yeah, this is more like the model calling a function on himself than a controller reading the model. Anyway i'll do it in an other way about the ui-router states giving your an answer in a few minutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90012/discussion-between-nick-russler-and-okazari).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would have done it this way ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mQE2QGW00JivehHionDM?p=preview)):

The routing :

```
$stateProvider
    .state('view1', {
        url: "/view1",
        templateUrl: "view1.html",
        controller:"WizardCtrlStep1"
    })
    .state('view2', {
        url: "/view2",
        templateUrl: "view2.html",
        controller:"WizardCtrlStep2",
        params:{
          playerId:null
        },
        resolve:{
          player:function($http, $stateParams){
            //you can use the player id here
            console.log($stateParams.playerId);
            return $http.get("test.json");
          }
        }
    })
```

I really really like to have a single controller per state. It avoid thing to get messy.

I also use a resolve to do the ajax call before the step2 view loading.

Here is the controller of the 2nd step

```
//I inject the "player" resolved value
controller('WizardCtrlStep2', function($scope, player) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  //to access the result of the $http call use .data
  $scope.player = player.data;
})
```

And finally the HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="main.playerId">
<button ui-sref="view2({playerId:main.playerId})">proceed</button>
```

Here i give ui-sref a param for "playerId" that will be used in the resolve function.

Hope it was clear, if you have any question feel free to ask.